# can't find Microsoft.Office.Interop assemblies in VS2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio, assemblies, office-interop, .net-assembly

I can't find Microsoft.Office.Interop assemblies in VS2012. I download assemblies from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508#system-requirements), but after installing I don't find assemblies. Then I try install Interop assemblies for Office 2007, but I get error "Please install Office 2007...". I use Windows 8.

Comment: To expand on that and be more helpful, just having the assemblies isn't enough.  You have to actually have Office installed in order to use them.

Comment: @DavidStratton I have installed Office 2010. I think if I haven't installed Office 2010 I get error message during assemblies installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll and found all the Office interop assemblies here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14